# cx_Oracle install issue on CentOS 6.2

Tags: python, linux, centos, cx-oracle

I feel bad posting yet another question on this, but all the others I've read through ended with a solution that doesn't necessarily apply or fix my issue.

I have Oracle running on CentOS 6.2.  Database is up, sqlplus connects fine.  I'm using Python 3.2 and Oracle 11.2.0.3

I found and installed the package cx_Oracle-5.1.1-11g-py32-1.x86_64.rpm without error.

```
[paws@linux ~]$ ls -al /usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages
total 360
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 May  2 12:04 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   4096 Apr 13 09:31 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    898 Oct  8  2011 cx_Oracle-5.1.1-py3.2.egg-info
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 353356 Oct  8  2011 cx_Oracle.cpython-32mu.so
[paws@linux ~]$
```

However when attempting to import cx_Oracle I still get an import error.  I've checked the PYTHONPATH as shown below, and the appropriate directory is there:

```
[paws@linux ~]$ python
Python 3.2.2 (default, Apr 13 2012, 09:15:56) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.path)
['', '/home/paws', '/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python32.zip', '/usr/bin/Python-3.2.2/Lib', '/usr/bin/Python-3.2.2/Lib/plat-linux2', '/usr/bin/Python-3.2.2/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2', '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages']
```

Is there anything else I can check to resolve this?  I've installed cx_Oracle many times on Windows without issues, but this is the first time on linux, so I must be missing something simple.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why it can't find it, but maybe try adding a symlink anyway (in site-packages dir: ln -s cx_Oracle.cpython-32mu.so cx_Oracle)

Comment: Unfortunately, the addition of the symlink doesn't seem to have any affect.  Same message as in the original post.  Strange.

Comment: wonder if it's a permissions thing...try >>>sudo python, then import cx_Oracle

Comment: Thanks for following up on this Gerrat.  Unfortunately, running as root returns the same message.  Very frustrating.

Comment: @Dwane...I'm relatively new to linux, but I find your question interesting, so I'm really curious as to what the issue could be.  Two more things to look at would be to cd to your site-packages directory, run python from there, and see if it will import it from the current directory; or see if: "import imp", "imp.find_module('cx_Oracle')" tells you anything.

Comment: Both good ideas.  However both also result in the "No module named cx_Oracle".  It seems clear that it's not looking where we think it is, but I'm at a loss to what else it could be.

Comment: No further ideas on this?  I've actually rebuilt the box (for an unrelated issue) and still have exactly the same error.  Very frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.  I wonder if its an issue with your [version tagged files](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/).

At the python prompt, what do you get when you enter:

```
>>>import sysconfig
>>>sysconfig.get_config_var('SO')
```

You should get:
*'cpython-32mu.so'*

If not, you could try creating a symlink to point to this.

Comment: I tried your statement above, and I get ".cpython-32mu.so"  (Note the leading dot).  Is this an issue or was your posting missing that?

Comment: Sorry...I missed that in my post (should have the leading dot).